# How can I programmatically determine if a device is connected to an audio jack?

Tags: linux, audio

Is there a way to determine in Ubuntu if there are devices plugged into the audio and microphone jacks?

I've searched for this and all the answers I've found have to do with detecting the action of plug or unplug.  I need to know if it's possible to determine if the device is already connected. The reason is we do a lot of automated testing and some of our tests rely on devices being connected to the machines. We'd like our tests to be smart enough to detect a device or not so they can behave accordingly.

If there is a solution, I eventually hope to port it over to OS X and Windows, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really mean audio jack rather than USB device: Those are purely mechanical/electrical connections, and the audio hardware is not set up to report back whether anything is connected or not.

You can try monitoring for audio on the microphone and seeing if any background-noise signal is present. After that, you could try playing a tone, or set of tones, through the speakers and seeing if the microphone picks them up. (Which it may not if this is a headset, but for your test environment you should be able to specify what equipment gets hooked up.) But other than that sort of "try it and see", I think you're out of luck.

Comment: You'd be wrong on this. Many codecs can in fact measure the impedance of devices connected to audio inputs and outputs without the need for an extra pair of contacts in the audio socket.  What certainly was (and likely still is) missing is any standard way of getting the information in user-space.  I've certainly seen Linux Codec drivers which support it, yet do nothing with the events that are detected.

Comment: Slightly surprising, but interesting. The answer still comes down to "unless you want to work at the driver level, or test at a practical level, you can't", though.

Comment: e.g. pavucontrol knows if microphone is plugged in or not